# Cannot implicitly convert type MyModel to System.Collections.Generic.List<T>

Tags: c#, generics

I have a model class like below,

```
public class MyModel
{
    [SQLite.PrimaryKey]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

and an Interface class where in I have a method who's return type is of type MyModel class method is like below,

```
public interface IService
{
   List<MyModel> IGetEmployeeDetails();
}
```

and the above interface has been implemented in my service class as below,

```
public List<MyModel> IGetEmployeeDetails()
{
    return _connection.Table<MyModel>().ToList(); 
}
```

Everything was working fine for me by the above implementation, but when I try to change my Interface method to generic return type I am facing problem with the return type of my interface method, like below

From `List<MyModel> IGetEmployeeDetails();` to `List<T> IGetEmployeeDetails<T>();` I'm getting

> Cannot implicitly convert type `MyModel` to `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>`

**Basically I want to make my interface method return type generic, but Im not sure how to typecast the results in my service class from MyModel to generic type**.

FYI I have tried below cases,

- `return _connection.Table<MyModel>().ToList<T>();`
- `return (List<T>)_connection.Table<MyModel>().ToList();` & etc

Any help is much appreciated in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Basically I want to make my interface method return type generic, but
>   I'm not sure how to typecast the results in my service class from
>   `MyModel` to generic type.

What you are looking for is generics in the level of the class and not the level of the function, as you tried.

If the function is the one that is generic then the caller specifies a `T` and the function has to deal with it. In your case you want different `IService` implementations, each being able to return a different collection. So:

```
public interface IService<T>
{
   List<T> GetEmployeeDetails();
}
```

And the derived:

```
public class DerivedService : IService<MyModel>
{
    public List<MyModel> GetEmployeeDetails()
    {
        return _connection.Table<MyModel>().ToList(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Gilad Green , this worked like a charm :)